# Positioning a face of a regular tetrahedron normal to a remote point

Tags: geometry

I have a problem in which I have a regular tetrahedron that can rotate about its centre with all degrees of freedom.

I then have a point, generated at random, to which I wish to align the closest surface of the tetrahedron such that its three vertices are all equidistant from this point.

The only initial information I have on this point is the differences in distance to the verticies of the tetrahedron.

My question is then, can someone help me as to how would I go about working out the transform to be applied to the tetrahedron in order for it to be correctly rotated into the required position.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Kevin.

Comment: Its not very clear what information you have about the remote point. Do you know how to calculate its coordinates?

Comment: The only information that I have about the remote point is the difference in distance to it as measured at the vertices of the tetrehedron.  This information is sufficient to determine the orientation of any given face to the remote point.  I just need to be able to calculate the transformation required to orient one of the faces such that it is normal to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the distance of an unknown point to a known point restricts the possible positions of the unknown point to a sphere around the known point with that distance as its radius. Knowing the distance to four points restricts the unknown point to the intersection of four spheres. Usually two spheres intersect in a circle, a third intersects that circle in two points, and the fourth can be used to choose one of the two points of intersection. Unless you have imprecise measurements or the likes, in which case you'd want to do some optimization to find the best fitting point position.

So now you know the coordinates of the random point with respect to the tetrahedron. The locus of all points which have equal distance to the corners of one face is the line orthogonal to that face and passing through its center. So you know the position of a point, and know a line you want to line up with that position. You could simply rotate around an axis orthogonal to both these vectors, by an angle equal to the angle between these two vectors.